# C++ unsigned int to double conversion

Tags: c++, qt, variables

What is the right way of converting `unsigned int` to `double`? I need this is for `QCPCustomPlot` for data setting, as it takes in `QVector<double>` **precisely** as parameter for creating a graph.

EDIT: Silly me. The 'memory leak' error issue was caused because I initialised `QVector<double> x(time), y(ipv4int)` wrongly. Changed the `time` value to the same as `ipv4int` (the data occurence frequency) and the `x` and `y` matched correctly.

Done with the `time` variable, now the actual issue regarding the conversion. How can I convert it to `double` format that holds value such as `1855919686` instead of in the format of `1.85592e+09`?

QCustomPlot requires `double` but it seems that the `QVector<double>` couldn't take in value like 1.85592e+09

Updated code:

```
QVector<double> x(i), y(totalIP); //i=236052
for(int o = 0; o <= i; o++){
    double dSec = arrayIPxTime[o][0] - startSecond; //arrayIPTime[o][0] holds time in second
    double dMin = dSec/60;
    double ipv4addr = arrayIPxTime[o][1]; //arrayIPTime[o][0] holds ipaddr in integer format
    x[o] = dMin;
    //y[o] = ipv4addr; this is the line that causes crash. 
    qDebug()<<"Count "<<o<<" time "<< x[o] <<" ipv4 "<<ipv4addr<<" arrayIPxTime[o][1] "<<arrayIPxTime[o][1];
}
```

Current output:

```
Count  236048  time  62.3167  ipv4  1.85592e+09  arrayIPxTime[o][1]  1855919686
Count  236049  time  62.3167  ipv4  1.85592e+09  arrayIPxTime[o][1]  1855919686
Count  236050  time  62.3167  ipv4  1.85592e+09  arrayIPxTime[o][1]  1855919686
Count  236051  time  62.3167  ipv4  1.85592e+09  arrayIPxTime[o][1]  1855919686
```

Comment: _"Converting unsigned int variable into double caused memory leaking"_ How did you get notice about that? That's usually not the case.

Comment: You _need_ to provide more details about what's happening. A simple conversion, by itself, _does not_ cause memory leaking. It is a wholly separate concern.

Answer (score 8):

Rest assured that converting an `unsigned int` to a `double` does **not** cause a memory leak.

Writing `double b = a;` is more than sufficient, or just pass `a` into the function that requires a `double` as a parameter.

Note that the conversion is *exact* for an `unsigned int` up to the 53rd power of 2, for an IEEE754 double precision floating point type.

Comment: Thanks for clarification that the conversion doesn't cause memory leak, maybe I misunderstood the error message?

Comment: The cause of the memory problem alluded to by the diagnostic is elsewhere.

Comment: Make sure you don't use template functions either, because that can cause some bugs too :)
For example if you add up double values between 0 and 1 using `std::accumulate`, but you set the initial value to an unsigned int, the operation performed on the elements will be integer addition. That is some nasty error.

Answer (score 2):

What's the value of `time`? It looks like you do:

```
QVector<double> x(time);
// [...]
x[o] = dMin;
```

If time == 166, no doubt `x[166]` is going to fail, since the vector is initialized with a size of `time`!

And by the way, nothing related to casting to `double`.

Comment: `time` holds value of `62.3167` minutes. As `double totalmin = totalsec/60` and `double totalsec = endSecond - startSecond`. `endSecond` and `startSecond` are `unsigned int` which hold values like `1313743347`

Comment: [QVector constructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#QVector-1) takes an int, so if `time` has value `62.3167` it will be initialized with a size of 62. Assigning directly a value to any index from 62 will likely fail at some point, but not necessarily at exactly `62`. I think you should consider resize() or using a like `i` in your case.